# Check if H2 db file exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2, spring-jdbc

I have been using a real simple H2 DB on a file.  I had my setup like this:

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:"+dbFileName);
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
```

and on application startup, I would simply do:

```
File dbFile = new File("~/mydb.db");
if(!dbFile.exists()) {
   String sql = -create my table here, etc...
}
```

But I am now trying to do this in a "correct" Spring Boot way.  So I have my application.properties file to contain this:

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/mydb.db
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

And I am trying to use the JdbcTemplate / Dao way of doing things.  But I need to check if the DB is there at startup.  So I want to do my previous check in the Application classes event listener for ApplicationReadyEvent.  But how do I get a reference to the datasource url?  I had is a a configuration property before and was automatically loaded,  and I could still do that, but it would be in to places and that would be bad.

So what's  the essayist / correct way to ensure this DB file is there when the application starts up.  (and I want this in a JDBC way,  no JPA please)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ApplicationListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) then parse the `spring.datasource.url` value:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationStartedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationStartedEvent> {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String databaseUrl;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationStartedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Application started");
        String path = databaseUrl.replace("jdbc:h2:file:", "");
        System.out.println(path);
        File dbFile = new File(path);
        if (!dbFile.exists()) {
            String sql = "etc";
        }
    }

}
```